# Histogram in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

What is wrong with this code?

```
File "<ipython-input-17-728073f2f109>", line 17
    {"$toInt" : 'page_start'}]}}},
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas what this means?

```
import pandas as pd

def length_vs_references(articles):

    res = {"1-5" : 0, "6-10" : 0, "11-15" : 0, "16-20" : 0, "21-25" : 0, "25-30" : 0, ">30" :0}
    n = {"1-5" : 0, "6-10" : 0, "11-15" : 0, "16-20" : 0, "21-25" : 0, "25-30" : 0, ">30" :0}
    
    cursor = articles.aggregate([
        {'$match': {'$and' : [{'references': {'$exists': False}
        }, {'$ne':['$page_end', '']}, {'$ne':['$page_start', '']} ]}},
        {'$project': {'len_refernces': {"$size": '$references'},
                                                'pages': {'$subtract': [{"$toInt": 'page_end'},
                                                                        {"$toInt" : 'page_start'}]}}},
        
            {'$bucket' :{
            '$groupBy': '$pages',
            'boundaries': [ 0, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 1000000],
                'default': 'Other',
             'key': {
                 'output': {"average": {"$avg" : '$len_references'}},
            }
                }
            }       
    ])
    return cursor
 

print(length_vs_references(articles))
```

Comment: I'm not going to try and count but you'll most likely be missing a bracket or have too many. Make sure they all match up

Answer (score 0):

You missed and added some `$`. Boolean values are `true/false`.

Should be this one:

```
articles.aggregate([
   {
      '$match': {
         'references': { '$exists': false },
         'page_end': { '$ne': '' },
         'page_start': { '$ne': '' }
      }
   },

   {
      '$project': {
         'len_refernces': { "$size": '$references' },
         'pages': {
            '$subtract': [
               { "$toInt": '$page_end' },
               { "$toInt": '$page_start' }
            ]
         }
      }
   },

   {
      '$bucket': {
         'groupBy': '$pages',
         'boundaries': [0, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 1000000],
         'default': 'Other',
         'output': {
            "average": { "$avg": '$len_references' }
         },
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have amended my code to the above and now receive OperationFailure: The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing', 'code': 17124, 'codeName': 'Location17124'}. Any ideas?

Comment: The error is quite clear, field `references` must be an array. You don't show any source data, so we cannot help.

Comment: Actually the aggregation pipeline is useless. You match on `references: { '$exists': false }`, .i.e. you select only documents where `references` does not exist but later you try to get the length of this field.